# Fitviewport LIBGDX for different stages/cameras

Tags: android, libgdx, resize, viewport

So I have read a lot about the fitviewport and cant get it working for my actual project. I have different stages, one camera for my menu/hud, and another camera for my tiled map.

My tiled map is rendered once per render but the trees layer is rendered twice (I want it this way). And cant get it fit properly.

BasicScreen:

```
@Override
public void render(float delta) {
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(.25f, .25f, .4f, 1f);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    cam.update();
    stage.getViewport().apply();
    game.getBatch().setProjectionMatrix(cam.combined);

    //stage.act(delta);
    //stage.draw();
}


@Override
public void show() {
    if (cam == null) {
        cam = new OrthographicCamera();
        cam.setToOrtho(false, Constants.VIEWPORT_WIDTH, Constants.VIEWPORT_HEIGHT);
    }

    if (viewport == null) {
        viewport = new FitViewport(Constants.VIEWPORT_WIDTH, Constants.VIEWPORT_HEIGHT, cam);
        viewport.apply();
    }


    if (stage == null) {
        stage = new Stage(viewport, game.getBatch());
    }

@Override
public void resize(int width, int height) {
    stage.getViewport().update(width, height,true);
}
```

MenuScreen:

```
@Override
public void setUpInterface(Table table) {
    skinStage = new SkinsStage(game, viewport, listener);
    infoStage = new InfoStage(game, viewport, listener);
    onlineStage = new OnlineStage(game, viewport, listener);
    settingsStage = new SettingsStage(game, viewport, listener, nightListener);
    statisticsStage = new StatisticsStage(game, viewport, listener);


if(map == null) {
        map = new TownMap(game, 1f);
        //camMap = new OrthographicCamera(Constants.VIEWPORT_WIDTH, Constants.VIEWPORT_HEIGHT);
        camMap = new OrthographicCamera(viewport.getWorldWidth(), viewport.getWorldHeight());
        camMap.setToOrtho(false, Constants.VIEWPORT_WIDTH, Constants.VIEWPORT_HEIGHT);
        camMap.position.x += 10*Constants.PixelsPerMeter;
        camMap.position.y += 10*Constants.PixelsPerMeter;
        x = 1;
        y = 1;
    }
}

@Override
public void render(float delta) {
    super.render(delta);
    camMap.translate(x,y,0);
    camMap.update();

    // Render Map
    map.render(camMap);

    // Render RayHandler
    map.renderRayHandler(camMap);

    // Render fore layers
    map.renderForeLayers(camMap);
}
```

The result is perfect when I dont resize. But when resizing the screen it turns weird:
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yPadX.png)

Any idea how can I implement it properly?

Comment: Instead of using a second `OrthographicCamera` for your Tiled Map, you can try to use a `OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer`

Comment: I don't know what `renderRayHandler()` is doing, but if it's something to do with box2D lights, it's probably indirectly rendering something to a FrameBuffer and whatnot. Anyway, that is probably setting some other gl viewport, so add a line right after it to restore your original viewport: `viewport.apply();`

Comment: @Tenfour04 Thank you that was the solution! Didn't know box2d Lights set other gl viewport. I need to investigate that